# Folders and files turned to green

Tags: windows-7, encryption

After formating my computer, some folders and files turned to green and now I cannot open certain files. From the properties of the disk, I am not able uncheck "Encrypt content to secure data".

How can I unencrypt my disk and make my data available?

Comment: Would you mind providing a bit more detail? Specifically: Did you reinstall your operating system? What operating system are you running? Would you mind providing us with a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 3):

The encrypt content uses [NTFS' Encrypting File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System) feature on your files, which makes use of Public Key Cryptography. If you haven't taken a [backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/back-up-efs-certificate#1TC=windows-7) of your [EFS certificates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223316), there's no way to recover them

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I create  EFS certificate?

Comment: you can create them, but it won't help restore your data because they've already been signed by the certificates and you no longer have access to them